# failed to open stream: Permission denied file_get_contents which generates XML FILE

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to generating an XML file, but error come in this [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) PHP function, this is my code:

```
 function mobile_login1($P1, $P2)
{
    $url = 'myURL';
    $data = array(
        'username' => $P1,
        'password' => $P2);

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $json_data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    
    
            $decode = json_decode($json_data);
            
            //print_r ($decode[0]);
            //
            
            foreach($decode as $row)
            {
                $data[] = array("Message" => $row->msg);
                    
                   
            }
             
             
            //print_r ($data[0]['Message']);
             
            $msg = $data[0]['Message'];
             
            if ($msg == 'Incorrect username/password')
            {
                
                 
                 $this->response['ResponseCode'] = "1000";
                 $this->response['ResponseMessage'] = $msg;
                 $this->response['ResponseData'] = $data;
            }
                
            else
            {
                if($decode != null)
                {
                    foreach($decode as $row)
                    {
                        $data[] = array("AccountId" => $row->a_id,
                                        "PersonalId" => $row->p_id,
                                        "FullName" => $row->full_name,
                                        "AccountName" => $row->a_name,
                                        "AccountType" => $row->a_type,
                                        "WalletBalance" => $row->wallet_balance,
                                        "PersonalAddress" => $row->p_add,
                                        "CompanyName" => $row->company_name,
                                        "CompanyAddress" => $row->company_add,
                                        "Fax" => $row->fax,  
                                        "PersonalMobile" => $row->p_mobile,
                                        "PersonalTelephone" => $row->p_tel,
                                        "Limit" => $row->limit,
                                        "Role" => $row->role,
                                        "AccountMobile" => $row->a_telno);
                    }
                
       
                    $this->response['ResponseCode'] = "0000";
                    $this->response['ResponseMessage'] = "successful";
                    $this->response['ResponseData'] = $data;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->response['ResponseCode'] = "1000";
                    $this->response['ResponseMessage'] = "no records found";
                }   
            }
           //return $json_data;
                
                
    }
```

when i try to call my URL error come is the Line Number `187` is the code where my **file_get_contents()** function.

```
A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: 
file_get_contents(http://myURL/mobile_login): failed to open stream: Permission denied 
Filename: models/accounts_model.php Line Number: 187
```

**Is this server fault or PHP error?**

Comment: You probably didnt set the permissions. Try `chmod("your/path/", 0777)`

Comment: Set the full Permission : chmod -R 777 /filepath/

Comment: Setting permissions on an HTTP URL is a bit pointless, guys …

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it turns out it was a problem with on my server:

I ran this line from the terminal to reslove it

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

thanks for the suggestion guys

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once - I've been beating my head against firewall settings for the last hour only to discover that it's just an issue with selinux settings

Comment: Thanks a lot, :) its a great help for me.

Comment: Saved me a ton. And to add, I had this on CentOS trying to connect to a webservice on the same box.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, as suggested above, the following worked for me on Centos 7

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a self-configured CentOS6 host with LAMP + Wordpress.  The Wordpress [wp_remote_get()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) function did not return results (and didn't return an error) nor did PHP file_get_contents().  Executing this on the host solved the issue.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```