# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://10.31.1.106:8080/gss-0.1/FileUtilities?wsdl'

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I hope someone can help me because I am looking for the solution since 2 working days...

I have a php website which need to request a distant webservice.
When I try it on my computer (Win7 + WAMP), it works well.
When I try it on the webserver (CentOs6), it return me the following error :

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
'http://ip_address:8080/gss-0.1/FileUtilities?wsdl' : failed to load
external entity "http://ip_address:8080/gss-0.1/FileUtilities?wsdl"
```

NB: the webservice is on the same network of my webserver (I do not use the same IP/port).

I know that the WSDL is accessible from the webserver because it is accessible using curl linux function.

```
curl http://ip_address:8080
```

My php code is:

```
<?php
$wsdl = "http://ip_address:8080/gss-0.1/FileUtilities?wsdl";

try{
        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl ,array('trace' => 1,
                                        'exceptions'=> 1,
                                        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
                                        ));
}
catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
}?>
```

Comment: Something external to this script is blocking access to ip_address or port 8080.  Whether it be a firewall, an unreachable service, or a routing issue, the script is unable to make a connection to that IP address.

Comment: Not sure. On the webserver I can access to the WSDL using the curl command.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found a solution but I don't understand the problem...

So I execute this Linux command

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

And now all is running !

[Response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783784/failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-file-get-contents-which-generates-xml-f): Thanks to user2533111

Answer (score 0):

If its not  firewalled there at your web server and its working in your local but not at your webserver(CentOS). its might be a case of different PHP version and php.ini settings.
Can you compare your PHP version and those below extensions in your CentOs server with your WAMP at local.

S0AP,
php_openssI,
openssI,
curI;

Comment: I compare the php.ini files and they are quiet similar.
SOAP, php_openssl, openssl and curl are all installed and they work.

I also try with a public wsdl and it works... So the php configuration must be good too... 
Now the question is: why it works with ('http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl') and it does not work with my proper WSDL created by JAX-WS ?

Comment: Here is a similar link that might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861077/soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-but-works-on-wamp